# drag folder shortcut to the left side of the dock

Tags: macos, dock

I wanted to drag my folder shortcut to the left side of my dock where all the applications are. the folder I have is just a folder with other apps in it from the same manufacturer because I dont want my dock to be very long I did it that way but is there a way to drag a folder to the left side of the dock or maybe an app that does the same thing.

Can this be done with the native Finder or do I need a third party app to add this feature for me?

Comment: There are a number of macOS dock replacements available that may do what you want, they are just a google search away...

Comment: @SteveChambers many people dont recommend that kind of stuff because it breaks your macOS down. which one would you recommend that wouldn't do that kind of stuff

Comment: I don't use them, so I can't recommend one. Knowing they exist I present it as a possibility. It's up to you to determine suitability.

Answer (score 0):

Folder shortcuts, & document shortcuts, are stuck at the right hand end of the dock. Apple doesn't offer any preference for that aspect of the Dock, & I would suspect any UI hack to do it of being dangerous.